# could not prepare statement (1 near "index": syntax error)

Tags: sql

После каждого рейса проходит плановая уборка салона. Результаты уборки вносятся в отчет-лист. Авиакомпания получила отчет, в котором указано, что во всех самолетах все места чистые, а спинки кресел исправные.

Выведите бортовой номер самолета, cформировав для каждой строки поле index с значением 'clean'.
В выборке должны присутствовать два атрибута — `side_number` и `index`.
Решение:

```sql
SELECT side_number, range as index
FROM airliners
WHERE side_number LIKE '%' AND index LIKE '/'clean'' ESCAPE '/';
```

Comment: `index` - одно из ключевых/зарезервированных слов в SQL, проще использовать какой-то синоним вместо него типа `idx` или же экранировать в соответствии с используемой СУБД `"index"` PostgreSQL/Oracle, `[index]` - MS SQL, `\`index\`` - mySQL и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Теперь буду знать, что index это зарезервированное слово.

Comment: ну да, это такая же сущность базы данных как `TABLE, VIEW, TRIGGER, FUNCTION` и куча других [mySQL](https://spec-zone.ru/RU/mysql/5.7/language-structure_reserved-words.html), [MS SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)  и др.

Comment: слово `index` не является зарезервированным в SQL, по спецификации это допустимый идентификатор. Но может быть зарезервированным в вашей СУБД, которую вы не указали

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT side_number, 'clean' as 'index'
FROM airliners
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]